# How to replace CardView in CoordinatorLayout with CollapsingToolbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm facing this problem that I want to replace the CardView in CoordinatorLayout in specific location like first photo

[image]
[image]
but when I center the CardView using `layout_gravity= "center"` the view will be like second photo 
I need to position the card view like in first photo .. how could I do that ?? 
this is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/bgColorPrimaryBlue"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="****">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/gradiant_background"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_image_height"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/worker"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="@font/el_messiri"
                android:paddingTop="140dp"
                android:text="User name"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_job"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:fontFamily="@font/el_messiri"
                android:paddingTop="175dp"
                android:text="Desc"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/bgColorPrimaryBlue">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlue"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_thumb_down_black_24px"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlue"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_block_black_24px"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryBlue"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using minus value for top margin in nestedScrollView

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-35dp"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <!--CardView and all of it's childs-->

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

and centered the card view programmatically using this

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
    final int cardMarginLeft = (width - cardView.getLayoutParams().width) / 2;
    ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) cardView.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.leftMargin = cardMarginLeft;
```

may be there is better approaches to solve this .. but this one worked for me .

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="exitUntilCollapsed|scroll">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="96dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/abc"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="140dp"
                android:text="User name"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/user_job"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="175dp"
                android:text="Desc"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/profile_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="220dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                    android:text="123"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                    android:textSize="30sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: this replaced the cardview but all of its parents disappeared ,and how you positioned it , I cant find the change in the code

Comment: app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" add this to cardview

Comment: can I use minus values for margin like android:layout_marginTop="-60dp" for example

Comment: yes I did .. I used minus value for the top margin of the nested scrolling and centered the card horizontally programmatically , I don't know if there is a better way to solve this .. that's why i didn't paste the answer .

Comment: what have you added here to position it .. this answer position the card view but removes its child views

Comment: @Mohammad check this **`app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center"`**